# Adding additional numerical values into already made column

Tags: excel-formula

Major noob here. This is my dilemma:

I created a spreadsheet on excel and input my data in a column. Then I was informed that I need to add two zeros (00) to the front of each value. Is there a way of doing this on excel w/o me double clicking each row and manually adding the 00's before the original value?

Comment: When you say value, are they numbers or text?

Comment: is this just for visual puposes?

Comment: Just combining numbers. So lets say i have value 12345, I need to add 00 before all the values in column A. It needs to show the 00, i wish it was just for visual but I need the 00 as they represent GITN code

Answer (score 0):

in order to add two leading zeros to numbers of unknown length, the only viable option I can think of is to turn the number into a string.

```
="00"&A1
```

There may be a way with the format text function to measure the length of your number then format with two leading zeros but that is currently beyond me.

The other option is to go into the custom cell format and change the display to

```
000000
```

Where the number of 0s is two longer than the number of digits in your number.  If your numbers are inconsistent in length you would need to do this for each cell.  It would keep the number as a number though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies. @Forward Ed your idea gave me a diff idea. I just added the 00's to the column before and then used another column + the CONCATENATE function.

Also for fellow cavemen like myself, you can use notepad to do it the ghetto way and copy then re-paste back to excel -.-

Im such an idiot lol. Thank you